# HTTP request fires when Chrome browser tab changes focus

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, google-chrome, debugging

When I change Tabs in Chrome, a HTTP request automatically fires for the focus Tab.

I expect a request to happen if I type a URL and press enter or if I click a submit button, but why is it happening just because I change tabs?

This is a problem as I'm trying to trace through code in a .NET application and my debug breakpoint keeps fireing from new requests that are not real.

I have include screenshots demonstrating the issue and a video with a simple Fiddler Trace using both Chrome and Firefox to demonstrate the requests.

please Note I turned off all plugins in chrome just incase that was the issue

**Watch Video Example**:

[Here is a video of the issue](http://youtu.be/KHpTJsdhm9k?hd=1)

Here are some screenshots of the issue:

**About to Click on a Tab, at the moment Fiddler is Empty**

[image: About to Click on a Tab, at the moment Fiddler is Empty]

**Clicking Chrome Tab fires request to the Server**

[image: Clicking Chrome Tab fires request to the Server]